# Indexon Firebase with push data

Tags: javascript, firebase

**Solved** -- I used the wrong database url.

I am saving data under a child called "insights" by the push() method which creates a unique key.

I want to call "insights" based on itemx = y using:

```
ref.orderByChild("itemx").equalTo('y').once("value", function(snapshot) {});
```

Therefore I need to ".indexon": "itemx" at /insights.

However, I can't get it to work. My rules are:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true,
        "insights": {
             ".indexOn": ["categoryType"]
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to factor in the auto generated key (e.g. -Js_4asFFFJPasdfErp9l)?

If so, how do I do it?

Thank you!

AB

Comment: What errors are you getting? In what way isn't it working? Also according to firebase docs: "Indexes are not required for development unless you are using the REST API. The realtime client libraries can execute ad-hoc queries without specifying indexes."

Comment: It's returning null. Is that because of the key that's between /insights and the key:value? or is that ignored?

Comment: You're indexing `categoryType`, but querying `itemx`. It would probably be a lot clear what's going in, if you provide a piece of actual data and real code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've solved the problem. I'm afraid it was me being stupid and calling the wrong database.

I appreciate your time and I'll be more careful in the future (including with providing real data.)

Thanks you.